# Softlayer API: How do I add a condition to allocation an ipv6 address when buying a host?

Tags: api, ipv6, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, virtual-server

I'm developing a project about softlayer API recently. Because the purchase of IPv6 alone must to pay. Now I wan't to allocation an free ipv6 address when buying a host. The current configuration of buy host is as follow:

```
vs_type = 'virtual_server'
vs_config = {
    'virtualGuests':[
        {
            'domain': 'a.com',
            'hostname': 'a-test-bandwidth-mouthly-pucharse',
        }
    ],
    'dataCenter': 'tok02',
    'hourlyBillingFlag': False,
    'imageType': 'public',
    'localDiskFlag': False,
    'maxMemory': 'RAM_1_GB',
    'networkComponents': 100,
    'operatingSystem': u'OS_CENTOS_5_X_MINIMAL_64_BIT',
    'privateNetworkOnlyFlag': False,
    'publicBandwidthCapacity': 'BANDWIDTH_250_GB',
    'quantity': 1,
    'startCpus': 'GUEST_CORE_1',
    'blockDevices': [
        {
            'capacity': 25,
            'device': 0
        }
    ]
}
result  = product_order_mgt.product_place_order(vs_type, vs_config)
```

regards~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to specify the VLAN where you ipv6 has been created, take a look to the documetation of the method:

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/createObject

you need to add this configuration to your payload

```
{ 
    "primaryNetworkComponent": { 
        "networkVlan": { 
            "id": 1 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The configuration is going to set the configuration for frontEnd network,make sure to use the VLAN id of your IPAddresV6.

Also your server needs to have enable IPv6 Address enabled, when you ordered a server via control portal you can see that options

[image]

I am affraid that option cannot be set using the createObject Method you need to use the placeOrder method and specify the price for that option. I recommend you to read this article http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/bpotter/Going-Further-SoftLayer-API-Python-Client-Part-3 in order to know more about the placeOrder method.

In case you ordered a GLobal IP adddress please see this documentation about how to assing the IP to your server https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/global-ip-addresses

let me know if you have more questions

Regards

Comment: I add this configuration like you said, but there is not allocated IPAddressV6. I set the id number 1. regards~

Comment: You need to use the VLAN ID where your ipaddress exists, take a look to this article let me know if you have more questions http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/phil/CCI-VLAN-Specification

Comment: When you ordered the IPAddressV6, it ask you for a VLAN you need to use that VLAN id

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I can add IPv6 when I buy the host. but how to get the information of IPv6?  regards~

Comment: I do not get it, how did you add the IPV6 to the host? and what information about the IPv6 do you want?

Comment: I want to restore the IPv6 address. So I need get the IPv6 address. I set the price item of ipv6 when I create device, then I can add the IPv6 when I buy the host.

Comment: ah ok, I saw your post with that question I will answer there.